# No setChannelMetadata() function in pubnub-angular2

Tags: pubnub

I am using PubNub in my Angular 10 project with Angular universal.
I am using pubnub-angular2, which does not have the `objects.setmetadatachannel()` method, so I use PubNub for it. As PubNub is a JavaScript SDK, it is working fine in a normal project, but giving an error while building in SSR mode. `npm run build:ssr` is fine but `npm run serve:ssr` is giving errors.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing like setchannelmetadata() so what worked for me is
using pubnub instead of pubnub-angular2
the two library i installed are:

1. pubnub
   2.@types/pubnub

i talked with pubnub support. they are not maintaining pubnub-angular2 anymore. so best not to use it.